# How implement google fonts when download the font in collection?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api, google-webfonts

i would like to use two google fonts, but my fear is that adding in this way:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

could be slower (in performance) than download fonts in collection...

So i download two fonts in collection, but i have doubt how i could to implement in my website...

Maybe i just have to insert the two collections in the css folder and than add in `head`

```
<link href='https://path/css/font/ ???????' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

but i don't know what file i have to link in path... For example when i download `PT Sans` in collection, in this folder i have these files:

[image]

I hope you can help me understand more..

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call your fonts in css file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(font1.woff); /* specify the path of your font location*/
}
```

Repeat this for next fonts.

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(font2.woff); /* specify the path of your font location*/
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "path of your font location" ? Tha path of folder with files (see the image in first post) that i have downloaded ?

Comment: No. It means if your style.css is in CSS directory and fonts in Fonts directory, then the path will be like src: `url(../Fonts/font2.woff);`

Answer (score 0):

You do need even more font files.

If you just open the file from the Google Server...

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic

... you see how it is done.

You link the font files from the CSS file - not from the link element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want your fonts loaded locally from in internal folder than an external source:

Add the folliowing to your code in a `<style>` tag:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PT_Sans';
    font-style: Regular;
    src: url('../fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Bold.ttf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('PT Sans'), local('PT_Sans'),
    url('../fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')

}
```

Or you can reference it externally in a CSS file.